# Where to download the latest 2.4.x Linux kernel while kernel.org is down?

Tags: nic, linux-kernel, sles, legacy

I need to run the pre-paleolithic (10 years old!) SuSE 7.3 under VirtualBox. (Don't ask. I just do, ok?) I managed to successfully install it. It boots. It recognized the virtual NIC (pcnet32 module) and I can see it has the correct virtual MAC VirtualBox gave it. But it can't communicate with the outside world. No packets pass through.

I want to try compiling the latest 2.4.x kernel on it, but kernel.org is down. Where else can I download this old kernel?

Also, I'm open to out-of-the box suggestions to get network connectivity to this OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to a Kernel.org mirror right into the 2.4 directory for you.

http://linux-kernel.uio.no/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/

Comment: Yeah yeah YEAH! The latest 2.4 has support for Intel Gigabit NICs, and <frankenstein>IT VORKS!!!</frankenstein>

Comment: lol. Enjoy your retro Linux :)

Comment: I'll celebrate playing Galaga and listening to The Smiths.

Answer (score 1):

Or here, too: ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/

But beware. As kernel.org was hacked you can't be sure if modified versions were replicated to these mirrors.

On the other side I just wonder if you setup dhcp networking on SuSE? Or manually configured the network? And if you run VirtualBox networking in NAT or bridge mode?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mirros. For example:

- [mirrors.ecvps.com/kernel.org/linux/kernel/v2.4/](ftp://mirrors.ecvps.com/kernel.org/linux/kernel/v2.4/)
- [ftp.task.gda.pl/mirror/ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/](ftp://ftp.task.gda.pl/mirror/ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/)

BTW, once Linus Torvalds said:

> Only wimps use tape backup: real men just upload their important stuff on ftp, and let the rest of the world mirror it;)

He was prepared :-)